# Visual studio and Unity does not sync

Tags: unity, game-design, unityscript, visual-studio

I'm pretty new to Game Development world. I'm using Unity 3D (4.6 - Latest version I think) and Visual Studio to code the script and something when I edit the script un VS 2013 and go back to Unity the script I edited does not match what unity "have". And Unity does not even show a compile error.

Exemple I have is :

(in a 2D environment)  i wrote this script

```
void Update(){
    Vector2 tweak = new Vector2(Math.Random(0f,0.2f), Math.Random(0f,0.2f));
    rigidbody.velocity += tweak;
}
```

Well unity gave me the error that rigidbody does not exist on the Transform (aright that's cool im in a 2d env. so it's rigidbody2D.velocity. I edited the script, with the fix, but Unity was still executing the line BEFORE the fix. I had to close VS and Unity to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Visual Studio Tools for Unity from Syntax tree http://unityvs.com/ You can debug Unity from within Vs with this plugin.